# Bootstrap multi-select not working in laravel view

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, bootstrap-multiselect

I want to make a multi-select dropdown with checkbox to select the options.

I've followed [this](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) to create a selector. I've used following cdn links

**CSS**

```
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**JS**

```
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
     <label>Assign Projects</label>
     <select class="form-control input-md" name="projects[]" id="projects" multiple="multiple">
         @foreach($projects as $project)
             <option value="{{$project->id}}" selected>{{$project->name}}</option>
         @endforeach
    </select>
    @if ($errors->has('projects'))
        <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('projects') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
```

This is working perfectly in terms of functionality but appearance is not as expected.

This is current view,

[image]

Can someone give me idea what's going wrong here ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.input-md').multiselect();
});`

Comment: I've added that on `JS` Still not working .

Comment: [http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect.html] Once visit this site. hope this will helpful for you

Comment: @BadriGs Main problem is with css since functionality is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed up this part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.input-md').multiselect();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bellow code in jquery.

```
setTimeout(function(){  
    $('#projects').multiselect(); 
}, 800);
```

This may help you !

Answer (score 0):

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.multiselect-ui').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
});
</script>`
Include this script and check(replace the class "input-md" with "multiselect-ui")